# Change values of all inputs in a set from any input in the set

Tags: angularjs

Say I have three number inputs that are bound to the models: `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Stick`.  These three inputs are related mathematically, so I want to run a function that will recompute the values of all other inputs when any one input is changed.  How could I accomplish this?  A perfect example of what I am trying to do is a conversion to multiple units.  If you change any one of the units then the others update their values.

I tried using `ng-change` with a function that did the required calculations and changed the models, but this resulted in me not being able to edit the `inputs`.  Perhaps the problem was because I was trying to edit the model that is calling the `calculate` function from within the `calculate` function.  Maybe I should pass a parameter and not update the particular input that is triggering the `ng-change`?

Comment: `calculate` presumably needs to know which input the user changed so that it can update the other two -- that could be one ng-change function with a param, or three separate ng-change functions, one for each field.

Comment: @DanielBeck I definitely would want to implement the former method over the latter, because there will actually be a large number of inputs (I just used three for the example).  That is the direction that I was thinking, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of passing the `$index` of the input changed to the `calculate` function.

```
<div ng-repeat="side in triangle">
  <input ng-change="calculate($index, triangle)" ng-model="side.angle" />      
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.calculate = function(index, array) {
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i != index) {
      array[i].angle = (180 - array[index].angle) / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5fYijghgl7Naz0fMtXb6?p=preview